# Laravel observer Update Event in not Triggering

Tags: laravel-5, observers, product-quantity

I used this in my update function:

```
 $qty = $request->input('checked_out_qty');
    DB::table('consumables')->decrement('remaining_qty',$qty );
```

i keep getting this error:

"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fixed`.`consumables_histories`, CONSTRAINT `251075_5c35eb169cb40` FOREIGN KEY (`checked_out_qty_id`) REFERENCES `consumables` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `consumables_histories` (`consumables_id`, `checked_out_qty_id`, `checked_out_by_id`, `status_id`, `location_id`, `assigned_to_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1368, 6, 1, 1, 1, , 2019-02-03 08:08:34, 2019-02-03 08:08:34))

but when u refresh the second time, the decrement still happens. what could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us how you are doing the update?

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Show us the code where you are updating the model. Also, did you register the Observer? See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers)

Comment: Yeah i did register it in the boot function

Comment: You can edit your question to add this code. Also, did you register the observer? Whenever you create a new one, you need to register it in your `AppServiceProvider@boot` method. For example `Consumable::observe(ConsumableObserver::class);`

Comment: I have registered it, my created even is working just fine, the update one, thats where the problem is

Comment: What happens if you `dd($consumable)` inside `updating`? Are you able to see it?

Comment: I used dd($consumable) but it did not trigger

Comment: Show us where you are doing the update action.

Comment: What file do u wanna see, cz maybe im getting u all wrong and that would help

Comment: The controller (maybe) where you are doing the update on the Consumable model.

Comment: thats my function

Comment: You are not doing any update action. Maybe you can consider the `saving` event instead. See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent)

Comment: i used the update function but i hit a snag, check out the question